# Push Zabbix alerts/notifications to Microsoft teams

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I want to push the zabbix alerts/notification to a Microsoft Teams channel instead of bombarding users email box with lot of emails everytime. Anyone has idea how to establish a connection between Zabbix and teams ?

Answer (score 0):

You have instructions and screenshots in the documentation: https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/msteams

Beside, there is no difference between flooding a mailbox and flooding a Teams channel: both can, and definitely will, be silenced.

Comment: Hi Iron, thanks for the response. I agree related to the flooding of messages but it would be easy for most of the people to see the alerts and comment at the same time.